# Run tests from multiple test files with Bazel in Python

Tags: python, bazel

I am getting started with `Bazel`, and so far I am trying to apply it to my old habits and patterns.

Suppose, I have my main programme split into several python modules, I can describe it in my `BUILD.bazel` with the `glob` function:

```
py_binary(
    name = "the_binary",
    srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
    deps = [],
)
```

This way, if I have files `the_binary.py` and, say, `two.py`, I will be able to import `two` in my `the_binary.py` module.

Now I want to test my modules, and I would usually write test files that correspond to my logic files, i.e. `test_binary.py` and `test_two.py`. However, when I try to use the `glob` function in my `py_test` section, I only have the tests from `test_binary.py` executed. The same happens even if I list all my test_files explicitly:

```
py_test(
    name = "test_binary",
    #    srcs = glob([
    #        "test_*.py",
    #    ]),
    srcs = [
        "test_binary.py",
        "test_two.py",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//the_binary",
        "//the_library",
    ],
)
```

Am I missing something obvious, or should I organise my code differently?